Neigbor-sum graph coloring algorithm
I've been able to generate a Python program that generates a sigma labelling of a graph. A sigma coloring is a vertex-coloring $f: V(G) \Rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that the color sums of the neighbors of every pair of vertices are distinct. The program utilizes a backtracking algorithm, while it is relatively fast for small $n$, it takes a lot of time for larger values of $n$. What other more efficient algorithm can be used t for this graph coloring?
Here's the snippet of the algorithm in Python:
# Sigma Coloring Init
def is_valid_sigma_coloring(G, vertex_colors):
    for u, v in G.edges():
        sigma_u = sum(vertex_colors[neighbor] for neighbor in G.neighbors(u))
        sigma_v = sum(vertex_colors[neighbor] for neighbor in G.neighbors(v))
        if sigma_u == sigma_v:
            return False
    return True

# Backtracking Implementation
def backtrack(G, vertex_colors, colors, vertex_index):
    if vertex_index == len(G.nodes()):
        return is_valid_sigma_coloring(G, vertex_colors)

    vertex = list(G.nodes())[vertex_index]
    for color in colors:
        vertex_colors[vertex] = color
        if backtrack(G, vertex_colors, colors, vertex_index + 1):
            return True
        del vertex_colors[vertex]

    return False

# Minimality Condition
def find_min_sigma_coloring(G):
    num_vertices = len(G.nodes())
    for num_colors in range(1, num_vertices + 1):
        vertex_colors = {}
        colors = range(1, num_colors + 1)
        if backtrack(G, vertex_colors, colors, 0):
            return vertex_colors, num_colors
    return None, num_vertices

# Graph Visualization
def visualize_graph(G, vertex_colors, title):
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    node_labels = {node: f"{color}" for node, color in vertex_colors.items()}
    nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_color='skyblue', node_size=500, font_size=10)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels=node_labels, font_color='red', verticalalignment='bottom')
    plt.title(title)
    plt.show()

# DataFrame Output
def print_color_sums(G, vertex_colors):
    data = []
    for u in G.nodes():
        sigma_u = sum(vertex_colors[neighbor] for neighbor in G.neighbors(u))
        data.append({'Vertex': u, 'Sigma Sum': sigma_u})
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.style.hide(axis="index")
    display(HTML(df.to_html(index=False)))
    return df

I tried the Welsh-Powell algorithm but it doesn't generate any such sigma coloring in my case.

The number of colors is unrestricted?

It is a known result that the number of colors is to be restricted from 1 to $n$ inclusive.
